# Wrapping a 2D numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Assuming I have the following numpy 2d array where `arr[2,0] = 7`.

```
arr =
[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]
 [7 8 9]]
```

How can I achieve a **wrapping effect** such that when I try to retrieve `arr[3,0]` for example, I won't be getting a *"index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3"* but will get `arr[0,0] = 1` instead in return?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can index one dimension at a time with with `take`:

```
In [72]: np.take(arr,3,0, mode='wrap')
Out[72]: array([1, 2, 3])
```

Comment: Bad idea. `numpy.take` can't return a view. It needs to copy all selected data into a new buffer, which gets very expensive for large arrays.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica, `take` and `put` are the only buitin functions (that I know of) that have `wrap` option.  Of course the OP could do their own index wrapping before performing the regular indexing.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica, `np.take` has favorable speeds compared to the equivalent advanced indexing, e.g. for `arr.take([3,7,10],0,'wrap')`.  For scalar indexing your own wrapping is faster.